# Stalling on Card Validation -- "Please Wait" for over 30 seconds

Tags: magento-enterprise, payment-methods, performance

This has turned into a frequent and reproducible occurrence. During checkout from the back-end, after entering all the customer information.. you select any of the payment type boxes (Check, PO or CC) and you get more than 30 seconds of "Please Waiting". Any ideas of what this might be or how I might trouble shoot it?

[image: Screenshot of the profile]

Comment: Where are those shipping prices coming from? My guess would be that your site is refreshing the available shipping methods after entering the payment and it is loading the shipping prices from an API which takes 5ever to respond.

Comment: UPS or Best Table Rates .. to pretty reliable methods. Not making much sense to me.

Comment: Since monday we have been having the exact same problem with our store using the UPS rate API. It's gotten so bad that we have stopped using UPS entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the UPS shipping methods and use flat rate or table rate instead. Since Monday, UPS's API has been going incredibly slow and just times out half the time. Your site is saying "please wait" while it is waiting 30 seconds to hear back from UPS's rate API. This is also slowing down the checkout on the front end so it is very important to stop using the UPS rate API if you want to keep your customers. We have switched to fedex for our store because this issue was costing us thousands in lost sales per day.